# can not start trousers service - giving error 'TrouSerS ioctl: (25) Inappropriate ioctl for device'

Tags: linux-mint, systemd, package-management, tpm

I have enabled TPM 2.0 using bios.

```
$ [ -c /dev/tpmrm0 ] && echo "TPM 2.0"
TPM 2.0
```

When I am trying to install `tpm-tools`, it is giving the following error:

```
% sudo apt install tpm-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
tpm-tools is already the newest version (1.3.9.1-0.2ubuntu3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up trousers (0.3.14+fixed1-1build1) ...
Job for trousers.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status trousers.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript trousers, action "start" failed.
● trousers.service - LSB: starts tcsd
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/trousers; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-02-10 03:59:26 AEST; 3ms ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 7414 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/trousers start (code=exited, status=30)

Feb 10 03:59:26 blueray-i5 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: starts tcsd...
Feb 10 03:59:26 blueray-i5 trousers[7414]:  * Starting Trusted Computing daemon tcsd
Feb 10 03:59:26 blueray-i5 trousers[7414]: /etc/init.d/trousers: 32: [: /dev/tpm0: unexpected operator
Feb 10 03:59:26 blueray-i5 tcsd[7420]: TCSD TDDL[7420]: TrouSerS ioctl: (25) Inappropriate ioctl for device
Feb 10 03:59:26 blueray-i5 tcsd[7420]: TCSD TDDL[7420]: TrouSerS Falling back to Read/Write device support.
Feb 10 03:59:26 blueray-i5 tcsd[7420]: TCSD TCS[7420]: TrouSerS ERROR: TCS GetCapability failed with result = 0x1e
Feb 10 03:59:26 blueray-i5 trousers[7414]:    ...fail!
Feb 10 03:59:26 blueray-i5 systemd[1]: trousers.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=30/n/a
Feb 10 03:59:26 blueray-i5 systemd[1]: trousers.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 10 03:59:26 blueray-i5 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: starts tcsd.
dpkg: error processing package trousers (--configure):
 installed trousers package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tpm-tools:
 tpm-tools depends on trousers; however:
  Package trousers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tpm-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 trousers
 tpm-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So, I tried to start trousers service. It is giving the following message:

```
    % systemctl start trousers.service
    Job for trousers.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
    See "systemctl status trousers.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
    % systemctl status trousers.service
    ● trousers.service - LSB: starts tcsd
         Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/trousers; generated)
         Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-02-10 04:04:56 AEST; 23s ago
           Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
        Process: 9114 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/trousers start (code=exited, status=30)
    
    Feb 10 04:04:56 blueray-i5 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: starts tcsd...
    Feb 10 04:04:56 blueray-i5 trousers[9114]:  * Starting Trusted Computing daemon tcsd
    Feb 10 04:04:56 blueray-i5 trousers[9114]: /etc/init.d/trousers: 32: [: /dev/tpm0: unexpected operator
    Feb 10 04:04:56 blueray-i5 tcsd[9120]: TCSD TDDL[9120]: TrouSerS ioctl: (25) Inappropriate ioctl for device
    Feb 10 04:04:56 blueray-i5 tcsd[9120]: TCSD TDDL[9120]: TrouSerS Falling back to Read/Write device support.
    Feb 10 04:04:56 blueray-i5 tcsd[9120]: TCSD TCS[9120]: TrouSerS ERROR: TCS GetCapability failed with result = 0x1e
    Feb 10 04:04:56 blueray-i5 trousers[9114]:    ...fail!
    Feb 10 04:04:56 blueray-i5 systemd[1]: trousers.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=30/n/a
    Feb 10 04:04:56 blueray-i5 systemd[1]: trousers.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Feb 10 04:04:56 blueray-i5 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: starts tcsd.
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing the comment made by the OP [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/633563/can-not-start-trousers-service-giving-error-trousers-ioctl-25-inappropriat/656680#comment1186884_633918), in which they want to take the code [here](https://pastebin.com/Wza5URRj) and rewrite it into a neater form.

I'm repeating the code here just in case it would disappear from the external site:

```bsh
    if [ ! -e /dev/tpmrm ]
        then
            log_warning_msg "device driver not loaded, skipping."
            exit 0
        fi

        for tpm_dev in /dev/tpmrm; do
            TPM_OWNER=$(stat -c %U $tpm_dev)
            if [ "x$TPM_OWNER" != "xtss" ]
            then
                log_warning_msg "TPM device owner for $tpm_dev is not 'tss', this can cause problems."
            fi
        done

        if [ ! -e /dev/tpm0 ]
        then
            log_warning_msg "device driver not loaded, skipping."
            exit 0
        fi

        for tpm_dev in /dev/tpm0; do
            TPM_OWNER=$(stat -c %U $tpm_dev)
            if [ "x$TPM_OWNER" != "xtss" ]
            then
                log_warning_msg "TPM device owner for $tpm_dev is not 'tss', this can cause problems."
            fi
        done
```

Sorting out the formatting and rewriting it into a single loop:

```bsh
for tpm_dev in /dev/tpmrm /dev/tpm0; do
    if [ ! -e "$tpm_dev" ]; then
        log_warning_msg "device driver not loaded, skipping."
        continue
    fi

    TPM_OWNER=$(stat -c %U "$tpm_dev")
    if [ "$TPM_OWNER" != "tss" ]; then
        log_warning_msg "TPM device owner for $tpm_dev is not 'tss', this can cause problems."
    fi
done
```

It's unclear whether the `exit 0` that the original script contained should still be executed if a device file doesn't exist.  I opted for using `continue` instead to skip ahead to the next device path (since the message said "skipping").

The only other things I changed was to remove the antiquated safe-guard with `x` in the second test, and I added a set of missing double quotes.

Alternatively, without `continue`:

```bsh
for tpm_dev in /dev/tpmrm /dev/tpm0; do
    if [ -e "$tpm_dev" ]; then
        TPM_OWNER=$(stat -c %U "$tpm_dev")
        if [ "$TPM_OWNER" != "tss" ]; then
            log_warning_msg "TPM device owner for $tpm_dev is not 'tss', this can cause problems."
        fi
    else
        log_warning_msg "device driver not loaded, skipping."
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This was answered by user [Minix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4252230/minix) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34706970/4957508):

The answer to that particular error message is a broken line in the given script `/etc/init.d/trousers`.

The offending line 32:

```
31:
32: if [ ! -e /dev/tpm* ]
33: then
```

gets expanded to:

```
if [ ! -e /dev/tpm /dev/tpm0 ]
```

Which provokes an error. Changing that line to something like:

```
31:
32: if [ ! -e /dev/tpm ] && [ ! -e /dev/tpm0 ]
33: then
```

should at least make the script work.

Comment: This exact code actually did not solve my problem. I modified the code in a medieval way. The code that worked is https://pastebin.com/Wza5URRj . I did not know what the loops are doing so kept them as it is. If someone can bring them in one loop then I will be glad to change it in my system.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ ! -e /dev/tpmrm ]
then
    log_warning_msg "device driver not loaded, skipping."
    exit 0
fi

for tpm_dev in /dev/tpmrm; do
    TPM_OWNER=$(stat -c %U $tpm_dev)
    if [ "x$TPM_OWNER" != "xtss" ]
    then
        log_warning_msg "TPM device owner for $tpm_dev is not 'tss', this can cause problems."
    fi
done
```